# Identifying a JieLin chip for an audio recording playback application

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am looking for a datasheet for a JieLin **AB21BP0L067-42A4** IC.

[image: picture of chip]

I visited the JieLin website and there is no result for the AB series.

Maybe it is discontinued, but this seems weird as the chip is being used in a product that's still being sold.

The product is a talking hamster which has a built-in microphone and speaker and records short/medium segments of sound and then plays it back through a built-in speaker. The played back audio is also pitched up. It also drives a motor which makes the hamster move.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about a semiconductor company named JieLin or Jie Lin. Also, part number on the chip is AB21BP**6**L... (couldn't read the rest).

Comment: https://site.china.cn/dianzixiangmuhez/3778390053.html but good luck getting any data.

Comment: Back in the 90’s I built a similar system using a 486 tower, but now I’d probably just use a dirt cheap microcontroller. My gut tells me this is gonna be one of those dirt cheap poorly documented micros.